# Não consigo fazer fechar a Janela do Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Bom estou fazendo uma aplicação em python ultilizando o tkinter, fiz uma janela login apos a verificação de usuário e senha eu gostaria que abri-se uma janela do sistema e fecha-se a janela do login. Estou quebrando a cabeça e não consigo encontrar o erro, se alguem poder ajudar estarei muito agradecido. Já pesquisei de tudo tentei ultilizar .quit .destroy mas não fecha.

```
from tkinter import *
from sistemas import Sistema

class loginJanela:

    def __init__(self):

        self.Janela = Tk()
        self.Janela.title('nome')
        self.Janela.iconbitmap('icone.ico')
        w = self.Janela.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = self.Janela.winfo_screenheight()
        size = tuple(int(_) for _ in self.Janela.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        x = w/2 - size[0]/2
        y = h/2 - size[1]/2
        self.Janela.geometry("280x280+%d+%d" % (x,y))

        self.fontePadrao = ('Arial', "10")
        self.container1 = Frame(self.Janela)
        self.container1['pady'] = 20
        self.container1.pack()

        self.containerDados1 = Frame(self.Janela)
        self.containerDados1['padx'] = 50
        self.containerDados1.pack()

        self.containerDados2 = Frame(self.Janela)
        self.containerDados2['padx'] = 50
        self.containerDados2.pack()

        self.containerBotao = Frame(self.Janela)
        self.containerBotao['pady'] = 30
        self.containerBotao.pack()

        self.titulo = Label(self.container1, text='LOGIN')
        self.titulo['font'] = ('Arial', '10', 'bold')
        self.titulo.pack()

        self.loginId = Label(self.containerDados1, text='ID:')
        self.loginId['font'] = self.fontePadrao
        self.loginId.pack()

        self.usuario = Entry(self.containerDados1)
        self.usuario["width"] = 30
        self.usuario.pack()

        self.loginSenha = Label(self.containerDados2, text='Senha:')
        self.loginSenha['font'] = self.fontePadrao
        self.loginSenha.pack()

        self.senha = Entry(self.containerDados2, show='*')
        self.senha.bind('<Return>', self.verificaSenhaEnter)
        self.senha["width"] = 30
        self.senha.pack()

        self.botao = Button(self.containerBotao, text='Entrar')
        self.botao['font'] = ('Calibri', '10')
        self.botao['width'] = 12
        self.botao['command'] = self.verificaSenhaClick
        self.botao.pack()
        self.mensagem = Label(self.containerBotao, text='', font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.mensagem.pack()

        self.Janela.mainloop()

    def sair(self):
        self.Janela.quit()

    def abreSistema(self):
        self.container1.pack_forget()
        self.containerDados1.pack_forget()
        self.containerDados2.pack_forget()

        principal = Tk()
        principal.title('IMOBILIÁRIA SK')
        principal.iconbitmap('icone.ico')
        principal.geometry("800x600")

        Sistema(principal)
        principal.mainloop()


    def verificaSenhaClick(self):
        usuario = self.usuario.get()
        senha = self.senha.get()
        if usuario == '' and senha == '':
            self.mensagem['text'] = 'Autenticado'
            self.abreSistema()
            self.sair()

        else:
            self.mensagem['text'] = 'Erro na autenticação'



    def verificaSenhaEnter(self, event):
        usuario = self.usuario.get()
        senha = self.senha.get()
        if usuario == 'skimoveis' and senha == 'senhasecreta':
            self.mensagem['text'] = 'Autenticado'
            self.abreSistema()
            self.sair()

        else:
            self.mensagem['text'] = 'Erro na autenticação'





lp = loginJanela()
```

Comment: Você tentou chamar o `self.Janela.destroy()` logo antes de criar a nova instância do Tk (na linha anterior ao `principal = Tk()`) e não funcionou?  Aparece alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: incrivelmente não da nenhum erro e tambem nao fecha.

Comment: Mesmo colocando o `self.Janela.destroy()` uma linha antes do `principal = Tk()`?  Testei aqui, no python 3.6 e funcionou. Qual versão de python você utiliza?

Comment: Obrigado!! era isso mesmo coloquei o destroy na funcao de abrir o sistema e funcionou, eu estava colocando na funcao de autenticacao do do usuario e senha, mas ainda não compreendo o erro o porque nao consigo fechar colocando lá

Answer (score 0):

Para fechar a janela anterior, você pode chamar o método `destroy()` da instância `self.Janela`, porém, ele deve ser chamado **antes** de criar a nova instância (`principal = Tk()`). O código da função `abreSistema` fica assim:

```
def abreSistema(self):
    self.container1.pack_forget()
    self.containerDados1.pack_forget()
    self.containerDados2.pack_forget()

    self.Janela.destroy() # <= Aqui, você "destrói" a instância self.Janela
    principal = Tk()
    principal.title('IMOBILIÁRIA SK')
    principal.iconbitmap('icone.ico')
    principal.geometry("800x600")

    Sistema(principal)
    principal.mainloop()
```

Caso prefira utilizar o método `sair`:

```
def sair(self):
    self.Janela.destroy()

def abreSistema(self):
    self.container1.pack_forget()
    self.containerDados1.pack_forget()
    self.containerDados2.pack_forget()

    self.sair()
    principal = Tk()
    principal.title('IMOBILIÁRIA SK')
    principal.iconbitmap('icone.ico')
    principal.geometry("800x600")

    Sistema(principal)
    principal.mainloop()
```

E não há necessidade de chamar `sair` dentro do método `verificaSenhaClick`.

Não é recomendado utilizar mais de uma instância do Tk na mesma aplicação e, possivelmente, o problema ocorreu devido à segunda instância ser criada antes da primeira ter sido destruída.

Uma alternativa, é você modificar a aplicação para criar apenas uma instância raiz, e abrir a(s) nova(s) janela(s) com o comando: `Toplevel` (documentação em inglês: [python](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-application-windows.htm) e [tkdocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#createdestroy))

Comment: Obrigado! Mas ficou ainda uma duvida, por exemplo se eu colocar a função `self.sair()` apenas nos metodos `verificaSenha` depois do `self.abreSistema()` ele não deveria fechar tambem ? Porque neste caso ele não fecha?

Comment: Acrescentei mais informações à resposta. A janela não fecha, provavelmente, porque existem 2 instâncias do `Tk` em execução